# how to call the jquery function in .aspx page to usercontrols controls in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

i have the following function in default.aspx.....i have webusercontrol which have 10 checkboxes and 1 button .... i want when i click on button1 of user control then it can access the function of default.aspx ...page ...if i dragged the usercontrol to default.aspx

Normally if i use 10 checkboxes and 1 button in default.aspx then it works fine ... if i use 10checkboxes and 1button in usercontrol then drag that usercontrol in default.aspx then it will not work ..

what was the problem ...how to fix this ?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>

<%@ Register src="WebUserControl.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" />

    </div>
    </form>
     <script src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

      $("#'<%=Button1.ClientID %>'").click(function(){

    var vCheckedCBCount =  $("input:checkbox").filter(function(index){ 
    return $(this)[0].checked == true;
    }).length;
    if(vCheckedCBCount > 1)
    {
        alert('You cannot check more than 1 check box.');
        return false;
    } 
});
 </script >
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one -->**

**------------------------------------ASPX Code------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**ASPX:**

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl/WebUserControl.ascx" TagName="ucCheckBox" TagPrefix="UC" %>

<UC:ucCheckBox ID="ucCheckBox" runat="server" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input:submit[id$='btnSubmit']").click(function(){

        var vCheckedCBCount =  $("input:checkbox").filter(function(index){
        return $(this)[0].checked == true;
        }).length;
        if(vCheckedCBCount > 5)
        {
            alert('You cannot check more than 5 check box.');
            return false;
        } 
    });
});
```

**------------------------------------ASPX Code------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**-------------------------------User control code--------------------------------------**

**UserControl:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControl_WebUserControl" %>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox7" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox8" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox9" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox10" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Continue" />
```

**-------------------------------User control code--------------------------------------**

Comment: why u use this ? <UC:ucCheckBox ID="ucCheckBox" runat="server" />

Comment: Can i use this directly in usercontrol ?

Comment: just like that you register WebUserControl in aspx page.In my case TagName="ucCheckBox" TagPrefix="UC" and in your case tagname="WebUserControl" tagprefix="uc1".see ur question.

Comment: put all check box and button control in usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

When you added the usercontrol to default.aspx, the ID of Button1 changed to `userControl1_Button1`

So you need to change `$("#Button1").click(function()` so that it will always have the correct name for the button:

```
$("# + <%=Button1.ClientID %> +").click(function()
```

Comment: You need to update your question to show the html where Button1 is declared.

Comment: I have updates ny default2.aspx page where i drag usercontrol ..have alook of updated code

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#'<%=Button1.ClientID %>'").click(function(){
});
```

A [**usercontrol**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.aspx) implements [**INamingContainer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx) Interface. So in order to get the elements using id you need to get the runtime generated id by using `.ClientID`.