# Jquery and webserver controls

Tags: jquery

I am learning jQuery and as part of that i tried following code.. It was simple exercise to see if i can manipulate server controls using Jquery.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestForm.aspx.cs"     Inherits="TestForm" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Hello</p>
  <a href="#">Click to hide me too</a>
  <p>Here is another paragraph</p>
  <input id="HTMLButton" type="button" value="HTML Button"  />

<script type="text/jscript" >
  //Desired Behavior. The Command button outside Form Attribute works are desired. 
  $("input").click(function () {
    $("#NameText").toggle()
  });

  $("#<%=WebCtrlJScript.ClientID%>").click(function () {
    alert("Button btnToggleDiv from Name Clicked");
    $("#NameText").toggle();
  });

  //This is simple HTML button inside Form Element.
  $("#HTMLInsideForm").click(function () {
    alert("Button HTMLInsideForm Clicked");
      $("#NameText").toggle()
  });


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function NameText() {
    alert("WebCtrlOnClientClick Clicked");
    $("#NameText").hide();
    this.blur();
  }

</script>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<div id="NameText">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <asp:Button ID="WebCtrlOnClientClick" runat="server" Text=".Net Button" OnClientClick="NameText()"/>
  <asp:Button ID="WebCtrlJScript" runat="server" Text="JScript Button"/>
  <input id="HTMLInsideForm" type="button" value="HTML Button(Inside Div)" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like anything i had inside form tags is not working.. for example first button with value="HTML Button" can toggle div element with ID ="NameText" where as other buttons irrespective of whether they are HTML or server controls cannot hide the div. I am not sure what i am missing.

Thanks
CSC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

`$('#<%= Button1.ClientID %>')...`

Unless you're using .Net 4.0. In which case you can use the solution presented here: http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Comment: Ugh, I was adding a response regarding ASP.Net 4.0 when you deleted and re-added your comment causing Stack Overflow to barf on me. But I would agree this is the most correct route.

Comment: sorry. I am trying your solution.

Comment: you mean something like      $('#' + <%= Button1.ClientID %>).click(function(){
  alert("Calling");
  });

Comment: Sorry its not working. I am sure i might be doing something wrong. Here is what i tried.  $('#' + <%= Button1.ClientID %>).click(function(){
    $("#NameText").toggle()
  });

Comment: Thanks Yads for the help. Your solution fixed the compilation error but its still not working the way i want. What i expected was that everything inside div tag with ID="NameText" should toggle when i hit Button1 the way it behaves when button with iD="HTML Button" behaves.

Comment: @CSC, your Button1 click handler is calling hide, while your Button2 click handler is calling toggle. Make them the same if you want them to do the same thing

Comment: I have edited my code to make it more readable. The buttons inside form element don't replicate the behavior of button outside the form element.
    1. The command button "HTMLButton" which is outside the Form element correctly toggels div element "NameText" .
  2. The command button "WebCtrlOnClientClick" which calls onclientClick even does not toggel the div element "NameText".
  3. When I debug my javascript, i do see that that div element is toggled when "NameText() javascript function is called but once i exit that function call the div element reappears.Not sure if postback is issue.

Comment: I found answer to my question. Thanks to following post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815521/how-to-call-the-jquery-function-in-aspx-page-to-usercontrols-controls-in-asp-net. I added        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input:submit[id$='WebCtrlJScript']").click(function () {
          $("#NameText").toggle();
          return false;
        });
      });  and the code behaved as i had expected. I had to add return false; in click event to leave the div element hidden. Thanks Yads for your help.